# Apple Mach-O Linker Error with Google Map SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

I've setup all frameworks mentioned in Google's Document.

And set architecture to armv7 and remove armv7s.

When I build the app, there 11 Mach-O errors mentioned below.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::push_back(char)", referenced from:
>         +[GMSPath polylineEncodedUnsigned:] in GoogleMaps(GMSPath.o)
>     "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::reserve(unsigned long)", referenced from:
>         gmscore::model::CollidableSet2D::StringValue() const in GoogleMaps(CollidableSet2D.o)
>     "std::_*1::*_vector_base_common::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
>         std::_*1::vector >::allocate(unsigned long) in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList.o)
>         void std::*_1::vector >::__push_back_slow_path(gmscore::model::ModelTriangle const&&&) in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList.o)
>         std::_*1::vector >::allocate(unsigned long) in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList2D.o)
>         void std::*_1::vector >::__push_back_slow_path(gmscore::model::ModelTriangle2D const&&&) in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList2D.o)
>         void std::_*1::vector >::*_push_back_slow_path(gmscore::vector::MutableStateTracker*&&) in GoogleMaps(GMSTilesEntityProvider.o)
>         void std::_*1::vector, std::__1::allocator > >::*_push_back_slow_path >(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr&&) in GoogleMaps(GMSTilesEntityProvider.o)
>         void std::_*1::vector >::*_push_back_slow_path(gmscore::model::Frustum2D const&&&) in GoogleMaps(GMSTilesEntityProvider.o)
>         ...
>     "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&)", referenced from:
>         -[GMSStreetViewScene fallbackNavigationAtYaw:nextPanoOffset:] in GoogleMaps(GMSStreetViewScene.o)
>         gmscore::vector::LabelSource::LabelSource(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, bool, bool, bool, GMSTileType*) in GoogleMaps(LabelSource.o)
>         -[GMSStreetViewView didTapPanorama:] in GoogleMaps(GMSStreetViewView.o)
>         -[GMSGLIndoorVectorTileProvider labelSourceWithLevelID:] in GoogleMaps(GMSGLIndoorVectorTileProvider.o)
>         gmscore::streetview::StreetViewLink::StreetViewLink(float, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&) in GoogleMaps(Overlay.o)
>         gmscore::streetview::Overlay::AddLink(gmscore::streetview::StreetViewLink const&) in GoogleMaps(Overlay.o)
>         gmscore::streetview::Overlay::OnScreenLink::OnScreenLink(gmscore::streetview::Overlay::OnScreenLink const&) in GoogleMaps(Overlay.o)
>         ...
>     "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::append(char const*)", referenced from:
>         gmscore::model::ModelTriangle::StringValue() const in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList.o)
>         std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > gmscore::utils::gmsutils::CommaDelimitedStringValues(std::_*1::vector > const&) in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList.o)
>         std::*_1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > gmscore::utils::gmsutils::CommaDelimitedStringValues(std::_*1::vector > const&) in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList2D.o)
>         -[GMSVectorMapResourceCache loadPolylineTextures:] in GoogleMaps(GMSVectorMapResourceCache.o)
>         std::*_1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > gmscore::utils::gmsutils::CommaDelimitedStringValues(std::_*1::vector > const&) in GoogleMaps(GMSPolyline2D.o)
>         gmscore::model::Triangle2D::StringValue() const in GoogleMaps(Triangle2D.o)
>         gmscore::model::CollidableSet2D::StringValue() const in GoogleMaps(CollidableSet2D.o)
>         ...
>     "std::*_1::__vector_base_common::__throw_out_of_range() const", referenced from:
>         -[GMSTriangleList triangleAtIndex:] in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList.o)
>         +[GMSTriangleList unpacked3DWithInput:tileCoords:] in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList.o)
>         -[GMSTriangleList2D triangleAtIndex:] in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList2D.o)
>         +[GMSTriangleList2D unpacked2DWithInput:tileCoords:] in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList2D.o)
>         +[GMSPolyline2D polylineWithPoint:point:] in GoogleMaps(GMSPolyline2D.o)
>         +[GMSPolyline2D polylineWithRectangle2D:] in GoogleMaps(GMSPolyline2D.o)
>         +[GMSPolyline2D unpacked2DWithInput:tileCoords:] in GoogleMaps(GMSPolyline2D.o)
>         ...
>     "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::operator=(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&)", referenced from:
>         gmscore::streetview::Overlay::GetLinkForYaw(float, gmscore::streetview::StreetViewLink*) const in GoogleMaps(Overlay.o)
>         gmscore::streetview::Overlay::GetLinkForTap(gmscore::math::Vector2f const&, gmscore::math::Vector2f const&, gmscore::math::Matrix4f const&, float, gmscore::streetview::StreetViewLink*) const in GoogleMaps(Overlay.o)
>         std::__1::enable_if<__is_forward_iterator, std::__1::allocator >*>::value, void>::type std::_*1::vector, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::allocator, std::__1::allocator > > >::assign, std::__1::allocator >*>(std::*_1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >*, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >*) in GoogleMaps(LabelingBehavior.o)
>         gmscore::renderer::Resource::set_name(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&) in GoogleMaps(GeometryUtil.o)
>         gmscore::renderer::TextureState::set_name(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&) in GoogleMaps(TextureState.o)
>         gmscore::vector::text::GLText::set_text(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&) in GoogleMaps(TextOverlay.o)
>         gmscore::renderer::ShaderProgram::SetShaderSources(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&) in GoogleMaps(ShaderProgram.o)
>         ...
>     "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::__init(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
>         gmscore::model::ModelTriangle::StringValue() const in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList.o)
>         std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > gmscore::utils::gmsutils::CommaDelimitedStringValues(std::_*1::vector > const&) in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList.o)
>         std::*_1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > gmscore::utils::gmsutils::CommaDelimitedStringValues(std::_*1::vector > const&) in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList2D.o)
>         -[GMSStreetViewScene setPanoramaData:] in GoogleMaps(GMSStreetViewScene.o)
>         -[GMSStreetViewScene recreateOverlay] in GoogleMaps(GMSStreetViewScene.o)
>         -[GMSVectorMapResourceCache initWithEntityRenderingViewContext:uiScale:] in GoogleMaps(GMSVectorMapResourceCache.o)
>         -[GMSVectorMapResourceCache createQuadVertexData] in GoogleMaps(GMSVectorMapResourceCache.o)
>         ...
>     "std::*_1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
>         gmscore::model::ModelTriangle::StringValue() const in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList.o)
>         std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > gmscore::utils::gmsutils::CommaDelimitedStringValues(std::_*1::vector > const&) in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList.o)
>         std::*_1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > gmscore::utils::gmsutils::CommaDelimitedStringValues(std::_*1::vector > const&) in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList2D.o)
>         std::*_1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > gmscore::utils::gmsutils::CommaDelimitedStringValues(std::_*1::vector > const&) in GoogleMaps(GMSPolyline2D.o)
>         gmscore::vector::ModelRendererValue::ModelRendererValue(std::*_1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, int, bool const&) in GoogleMaps(GMSColoredOverlayEntityProvider.o)
>         gmscore::vector::ModelRendererValue::ModelRendererValue(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, int) in GoogleMaps(Overlay.o)
>         gmscore::model::Triangle2D::StringValue() const in GoogleMaps(Triangle2D.o)
>         ...
>     "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
>         -[GMSTriangleList description] in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList.o)
>         gmscore::model::ModelTriangle::StringValue() const in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList.o)
>         std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > gmscore::utils::gmsutils::CommaDelimitedStringValues(std::_*1::vector > const&) in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList.o)
>         -[GMSTriangleList2D description] in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList2D.o)
>         std::*_1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > gmscore::utils::gmsutils::CommaDelimitedStringValues(std::__1::vector > const&) in GoogleMaps(GMSTriangleList2D.o)
>         -[GMSStreetViewScene setPanoramaData:] in GoogleMaps(GMSStreetViewScene.o)
>         -[GMSStreetViewScene recreateOverlay] in GoogleMaps(GMSStreetViewScene.o)
>         ...
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: [Follow these instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project)

Answer (score 9):

This means you are not linking the C++ standard library. Do that by going to Project->Build Setting and add the framework `libc++.dylib`.

Comment: libc++.dylib is the one - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chris and Matt.